# Why does this array creation not work in php7?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, php-7

This is the code I'm using to create an array for a WordPress site.

```
foreach ($terms as $item) {
    $location_no++;
    $term_id = $item->term_id;
    $term_name = $item->name;
    $latitude = get_field('latitud', 'term_' . $term_id);
    $longitude = get_field('longitud', 'term_' . $term_id);

    // Populate the array!
    $locations[$location_no] = array (
        'id' => $location_no,
        'lat' => $latitude,
        'long' => $longitude,
        'name' => $term_name,
    );
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($locations);
echo '</pre>';
```

the print_r() produces this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [lat] => 40.423560
            [long] => -3.702541
            [name] => Madrid
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [lat] => 40.423560
            [long] => -3.702541
            [name] => Madrid
        )

)

...
```

However when I switch over to php7.1, the array no longer works and I get this instead:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

A var_dump() of $terms produces this:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(WP_Term)#7136 (10) {
    ["term_id"]=>
    int(28)
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "Madrid"
    ["slug"]=>
    string(6) "madrid"
    ["term_group"]=>
    int(0)
    ["term_taxonomy_id"]=>
    int(28)
    ["taxonomy"]=>
    string(14) "trip_locations"
    ["description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["parent"]=>
    int(71)
    ["count"]=>
    int(5)
    ["filter"]=>
    string(3) "raw"
  }
}
```

Why oh why is this happening?

Comment: What do you get if you var_dump($terms); ?

Comment: @RemcoK. I have amended my question with the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a two dimensional array and you dont have to loop it the way you loop a one-dimensional array.
When looping you can provide index to access the inner array.
Do this:

```
foreach($location as $key => $value){
   echo $value["id"]."<br>";
   echo $value["lat"]."<br>";
   echo $value["long"]."<br>";
   echo $value["name"]."<br>";
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure where this code will go, or if it indeed will replace something.

Answer (score -1):

**What happens if you try this?**

```
$locations = [];

foreach ($terms as $location_no => $item) {

    $term_id = $item->term_id;
    $term_name = $item->name;
    $latitude = get_field('latitud', 'term_' . $term_id);
    $longitude = get_field('longitud', 'term_' . $term_id);

    // Populate the array!
    $locations[$location_no] = [
        'id' => $location_no,
        'lat' => $latitude,
        'long' => $longitude,
        'name' => $term_name,
    ];
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($locations);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Please do not use answers to ask clarification questions. Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: This overwrites the array with every iteration, so it produces an array with the last result

Comment: I don't think so because the $location_no will be the key of the array at the current position.

Comment: @PatrikAlienus Okay, but the array you provided does also contain one key. Or did you cut it?